# How to load UI on navigated page(2nd page) according to the grid clicked on first page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am working on a windows store 8.1 app, I have added Grids in MainPage.xaml using List in MainPage.xaml.cs

MainPage.xaml

```
<GridView Margin="20" x:Name="main" SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="main_ItemClick">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Background="Red" Width="250" Height="200">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Row="0" Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="{Binding ImageLocation}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="28" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SubTitle}" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="16" />

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    List<data> myList = new List<data>();
    myList.Add(new data()
        {
            ImageLocation = @"Assets/network.png",
            iName = "NetWork",
            SubTitle ="Network",
            Title = "Network"
        });
    myList.Add(new data()
    {
        ImageLocation = @"Assets/fb.png",
        iName = "Facebook",
        SubTitle = "Facebook",
        Title = "Facebook"
    });


    main.ItemsSource = myList;
}

private void main_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(ListView));
}
```

I want that when someone click on any of the grids, a TextBlock in ListView page show which grid was clicked in MainPage .

Comment: You shouldn't be navigating to `typeof(ListView)`. If anything, you should definitely rename that page, as it collides with the `ListView` class. As to what you can do, Frame.Navigate can pass in a parameter. Your ItemClickEventArgs has a ClickedItem property which tells you which item was clicked (like which grid). You can take that value and pass it in to the navigation parameter. You can then retrieve that in your 'ListView' in the OnNavigatedTo method. Or you could use a ViewModel to pass data between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be a challenge to explain without showing you in code, but here goes...

Hopefully you have created two pages so far. MainPage.xaml that holds your GridView. And a DetailsPage.xaml that will have the layout to show one item.

In the code-behind of MainPage.xaml, like you have in your sample code, you handle the ItemCLick of the GridView, but you want to get the Id of the item clicked, not the item itself. The reason for this is that you want to pass a string, and not a complex object.

In your handler, the event args (e) has a property called ClickedItem that will be the item you are binding to. Let's pretend it's a UserObject you are binding to. In your handler do something like this:

```
var user = e.ClickedItem as UserObject;
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(DetailPage), user.Id.ToString());
```

So, what's happening here? Almost the same code you had before. Except you are navigating to the type of the second page instead of anything else. You are also passing in (the second argument in the Navigate method) the exact record you want to show.

Then in your DetailPage.xaml code-behind you ned to override the OnNavigatedTo method. This method is what is invoked when the Navigation framework directs to the page. It's has a NavigationPararmeter passed to it that you can use to extract the key you passed.

I think it's actually args.Parameter you want to use. You can parse it to an integer and use that to fetch the individual record you have somehow in memory in your application.

```
var id = int.Parse(args.Parameter);
var user = YourFactory.GetUser(id);
```

> The reason I shifted from this is how you do it to "I think this is how it works" is because although the basic framework operates like this, most developers do not use it like this. Most developers implement something like Prism.StoreApps which introduces not only a lightweight MVVM framework, but also a sophisticated NavigationService that lets you inject parameters directly into an auto-associated view model.

But based on the simplicity of your question, try not to pay attention to that last bit. I explained the basic workflow using the in-box framework. It works just fine, and it will get the job done. When you are ready to write a more advanced implementation you can investigate Prism.StoreApps

> More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xx130655.aspx

Best of luck!